# How to make a Python loop that writes to CSV in different rows?

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am new to Python and I have a script that grabs the Yahoo Finance company name, sector, and industry info based on tickers that I want, and everything gets written to CSV in different cells but in one row. How do I make each excel row display company name, sector, and industry per ticker that I enter?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import csv

def get_all():
    results = []
    for x in tickers:
        try:
            website = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/profile?p={0}".format(x)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get(website)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            company = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/h3')))
            results.append(company.text)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            sector = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Sector']/following-sibling::strong")))
            results.append(sector.text)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            industry = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Industry']/following-sibling::strong")))
            results.append(industry.text)
            driver.close()
        except Exception as e: 
            error_msg = "Error on {0}-{1}".format(x,e) 
            results.append(error_msg)
            driver.close()
    print(results)
    out = csv.writer(open("yahoo_companies.csv","w"), delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    out.writerow(results)

# Enter tickers below
tickers = ['COST', 'BBY']
get_all()
```

For example, I want this to give me (Each semicolon would be a different cell):

Row 1: Costco Wholesale Corporation; Services; Discount, Variety Stores

Row 2: Best Buy Co., Inc.; Services; Electronics Stores

Row 3: Etc...

Right now I get (All in Row 1): Costco Wholesale Corporation; Services; Discount, Variety Stores; Best Buy Co., Inc.; Services; Electronics Stores

Comment: Check your indentation and `result` declaration.

Comment: just a little question, why you use requests instead selenium ?  by the way, is better if you use the API 
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/COST?formatted=true&crumb=weDstZA%2F.lj&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=assetProfile%2CsecFilings%2CcalendarEvents&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Also, I am learning requests I heard it is much faster.

Comment: @wu4m4n: The link you posted shows all of the company information already in dictionary form. How can I grab this information in a new script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of each row you should have a newline character (\n\r) for the CSV editing programme to understand.

If you add each row into its own list and append that to the main 'results' list,*writerows* will add the line termination for you for each element.

See the following code.

```
def get_all():
    results = []
    for x in tickers:
        # declare a new list to hold the values in each row
        newRow = []
        try:
            website = "http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{0}/profile?p={0}".format(x)
            driver = webdriver.Chrome()
            driver.get(website)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            company = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-0-Quote-Proxy"]/section/div[2]/section/div/div[1]/div/h3')))
            # appending to newRow list
            newRow.append(company.text)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            sector = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Sector']/following-sibling::strong")))
            # appending to newRow list
            newRow.append(sector.text)
            wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
            industry = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[. = 'Industry']/following-sibling::strong")))
            # appending to newRow list
            newRow.append(industry.text)
            driver.close()
        except Exception as e: 
            error_msg = "Error on {0}-{1}".format(x,e) 
            # appending to newRow list
            newRow.append(error_msg)
            driver.close()
        # append the newRow list into 'results list'
        results.append(newRow)
    print(results)
    outFile = open("yahoo_companies.csv","w")
    out = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    # see the following line, its writerows (plural). different to your code.
    out.writerows(results)
    outFile.close()
```